# jQuery Form Validation Working in Mozilla and Internet Explorer, but not in Chrome or Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari, validation

I've taken an exact copy of an existing working Contact Form… http://dev.rapweb.co.uk/rapport-form-test/

In Chrome and Safari the validation takes no effect.

I've found other people with similar problems, who have had suggestions made to try alternate ways of submitting the form, but after trying these alternate methods, the form validation still fails in Chrome and Safari.

I'm baffled... Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: in second paragraph you said it work in Chrome but next paragraph you said its not working in Chrome.??

Comment: Everything, but the validation is working Chrome and Safari.
Maybe I should have left out what is working and just stuck to what isn't. Apologies!

Comment: have you checked error on console in chrome? using **F12**

Comment: Please paste you code in http://pastbin.com or http://ideone.com/ and give the link.

Comment: Thanks... I was unaware of this "error on console" and will look into it now.

Comment: The link to the code is... http://ideone.com/7RkXg
After a brief read, I think JavaScript (rhino) was the best choice over JavaScript (spidermonkey).
However, the solution below has solved my problem, which I will respond to now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign validation rules after 'document ready' event
So all code of js/script.js must be in $(function(){ /*contents of js/script.js*/ });

Comment: Since he is calling the javascript code at the end of the page, that is not the problem.

Comment: Many thanks "alrusdi"!

Your solution works in all browsers! I really appreciate your help and everyone else who has contributed!

Latest link... http://dev.rapweb.co.uk/rapport-form-test/test.htm

Comment: OMG! it is the bug in WebKit https://bugs.launchpad.net/sheltermanager/+bug/695302
author must rename variable name to something else in 
var name = $('#name'); line